# Nodejs Tedious Mssql Slow Performance

Tags: node.js, sql-server, performance, tedious

I'm running some HTTP load test throught a simple NodeJS route that perform a request on differents database and returning result to client by using ***Vegeta*** (https://github.com/tsenart/vegeta) but I'm facing to slow performance with the MSSQL tedious pool connector (https://github.com/tediousjs/tedious-connection-pool).

The test was run with those configurations :

- Request (this is a simple request) : **SELECT *fields1* FROM *table***
- Pool min : ***10***
- Pool max : ***100***
- rate : ***1000 request (per seconds)***
- duration : ***30sc***

Here are the results :

1. Percentage of sucess :

   - MSSQL (package : ***tedious-connection-pool***) : ***60% of requests was success*** and the ***30% fail*** with this message sometimes : read tcp 127.0.0.1:55998->127.0.0.1:8000: read: connection reset by peer
   - MySQL (package : ***mysql***) : ***100% success***
   - PostgreSQL (package : ***node-postgres***) : ***100% success***
2. Mean latency :

   - MSSQL (package : ***tedious-connection-pool***) : ***39sc***
   - MySQL (package : ***mysql***) : ***100ms***
   - PostgreSQL (package : ***node-postgres***) : ***50ms***

I don't think that problem come from server configuration or code implementation, because all databases are on the same server but not running at the same time for the test and the code of the NodeJS route is very basic and this is the same for each connector.

In addition I've perform a Jmeter test to only test the request on SQL Server, and no problems, the latency graph was good (latency graph show line under 800ms during the period of the test).

Someone have face to similar problem or have any idea about the slow performance on SQL Server (*I think that the slow performance on the SQL Server database comes from the tedious driver but I'm not sure, and I don't know how to determine it*) ?

Comment: Hi Loïc Fontaine, facing a similar issue. Did you have any results with this?

Comment: Hi, I didn't find a solution for that, but for sure tedious was the main problem on mssql.